# enter password/name for git and hg in python / shell

Tags: python, git, shell, github, mercurial

I would like to enter the name and password for git and the password for github from a python/shell script

But  :

```
echo mypasswd | hg push
```

As :

```
echo myname mypasswd | git push origin master
```

Does not work

Comment: Not sure is there a way to pass the password as an parameter but its achievable using expect programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when you want to provide answers to interactive commands you'll do it with something like this:

```
myCommand <<EOF  
some answer  
some other answer  
EOF
```

But I'm afraid you can't use this kind of redirection / piping to provide passwords to your commands. As [@Fidel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2609158/fidel) pointed it out, you should check the `expect` command for that.

Also, you should authenticate on your SCM using rsa keys ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

`git pull https://[user]:[passwd]github.com/[account]/[repo].git [branch]`

Or add it as a remote:

```
git remote add origin https://[user]:[passwd]@github.com/[account]/[repo].git
```

If you want to keep the name `origin` for the new remote, you should delete the old one first by using `git remote remove origin`

Answer (score 1):

For Mercurial, you should take a look at how you can [store HTTPS credentials](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/remote/#caching-of-http-s-credentials). There are several options: you can store the password in a [config file](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#auth), you can use the [keyring extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeyringExtension) or you can hard-code it into the URL:

```
hg pull https://username:password@host/repo
```

Only put the password into the URL if you're on a trusted machine — other people logged into the machine will be able to see the password while your `hg pull` is running.